# Trying to await elements of object in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm making call to an API that returns a list of fields. Some of those fields have related fields, which I need to query the API to get those fields as well.

So here's what I'm attempting to do (mostly pseudo code):

```
// gets initial set of fields. This part works.
let fields = await getFields();
processFields(fields).then(data => {
    console.log('data now contains object with all fields and related fields', data);
});

async function processFields(fields) {
    let fieldObj = {};

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fields.forEach(async field => {
            if (field.collection) {
                let related = await getRelated(field.relatedListFieldType);
                fieldObj[field.id] = {
                    name: field.name,
                    display: field.display,
                    fields: related
                };
            } else {
                fieldObj[field.id] = {name: field.name, display: field.display};
            }
        });

        resolve(fieldObj);
    });
}

async function getRelated(name) {
    … some code here and return promise …
}
```

The issue that I'm running into is forEach doesn't wait, so in put first console.log, I get all the results back that I'm expecting except for the fields that have a collection. Since I'm awaiting those, it never gets entered into the returned fieldObj. If I don't await there, I get them in the fieldObj, but when I print them out, they're just promises.
I've been trying unsuccessfully to use bluebird and the async npm library to try to get a foreach that will wait for results before resolving, but I haven't been successful. What can I do to get through this?

Edit with new code:

```
async function processFields(data) {

    let fieldObj = {};

    for (let field of data.data) {
        if (field.isCollection) {
            let related = await getRelated(field.relatedListFieldType);
            fieldObj[field.id] = {
                name: field.name,
                display: field.display,
                fields: related
            };
        } else {
            fieldObj[field.id] = {
                name: field.name,
                display: field.display
            }
        }
    }

    return fieldObj;
}

async function getRelated(name) {
    let relatedData = '';

    name = name.toLowerCase();
    if (objects[name]) {
        return objects[name];
    } else {
        // put a placeholder here so we only request this once
        objects[name] = {};
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let relatedOptions = Object.assign(options, {
            path: encodeURI(`/api/objects/v1/${name}/_describe`)
        });

        let req = https.request(relatedOptions, res => {
            res.on('data', chunk => {
                relatedData += chunk;
            });

            res.on('error', err => {
                console.log('had error', err);
            });

            res.on('end', async () => {
                objects[name] = await processFields(JSON.parse(relatedData));
                resolve(objects[name]);
            });
        });

        req.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: async/await doesn't work like you think inside `forEach`

Comment: Default forEach funciton doesn't support promise. Use for instead

Comment: also, why mix` await` and `.then` in the first two lines of code `let fields = await getFields();
processFields(fields).then` - not that it's wrong, just odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for`, not `.forEach()` to get the loop to wait with `await`.  `.forEach()` is not designed to pause with `await`.

There's also no reason to create your own promise.  The `async` function already returns a promise so you can just use `await` and then return a value which will automatically become the resolved value of the returned `async` promise.

For example, you can do it like this:

```
async function processFields(fields) {
    let fieldObj = {};

    for (let field of fields) {
        if (field.collection) {
            let related = await getRelated(field.relatedListFieldType);
            fieldObj[field.id] = {
                name: field.name,
                display: field.display,
                fields: related
            };
        } else {
            fieldObj[field.id] = {name: field.name, display: field.display};
        }
    }
    return fieldObj;
}
```

Comment: I chose this answer because of the great explanation! I still had a bit of work to do. The getRelated function was being called a bunch of times on the same fields, and the values are cached in an object, and since I didn't have the value yet, it would just keep calling it on the same field. So I started storing a placeholder in the object the first time it's called for each field, then each call would return that placeholder until it was replaced with the value from the promise, and life is now good!

Comment: @FrancisLewis - If "Didn't have the value yet" is causing a problem, then it sounds like maybe you're not using promises correctly inside of `getRelated()`.  The promises should coordinate the timing for you if done properly.  Perhaps you need to show that code so we can help you fix it to properly resolve the way it should.

Comment: I just edited my post with the new code. I'm definitely not 100% positive I'm using the best approach for getRelated. It's working at the moment, but if you have some ideas to improve that, I would definitely appreciate it!

Comment: @FrancisLewis - What you have is fine.  I'd personally use the `request-promise` library rather than promisify it myself.

Comment: Woah! that was easy! I'm all for not re-creating the wheel every time one is needed.

Answer (score 1):

`fields.forEach` doesn't wait for the promises, therefore you are resolving before any async code has completed

use for ... of

Then there's no need for a Promise constructor either

```
async function processFields(fields) {
    let fieldObj = {};

    for (let field of fields) {
        if (field.collection) {
            let related = await getRelated(field.relatedListFieldType);
            fieldObj[field.id] = {
                name: field.name,
                display: field.display,
                fields: related
            };
        } else {
            fieldObj[field.id] = {name: field.name, display: field.display};
        }
    }
    return fieldObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function processFields(fields) {
    let fieldObj = {};

    for(var field of fields) {
        if (field.collection) {
                let related = await getRelated(field.relatedListFieldType);
                fieldObj[field.id] = {
                    name: field.name,
                    display: field.display,
                    fields: related
                };
            } else {
                fieldObj[field.id] = {name: field.name, display: field.display};
            }
    }
    return fieldObj;
}
```

Comment: an answer, edited to duplicate two existing correct answers, with just code and no explanation is not very useful